# WordPress wpautop/shortcode generating invalid markup

Tags: shortcode, wp-autop

I notice that theres invalid markup in my shortcode. Its ok if I disable `wpautop` tho

```
function shortcode_banner($attrs, $content = '') {
    echo ' --- ' . $content . ' --- ';
    $html = '<section id="banner"><div class="wrap">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></section>';
    die($html);
}
```

When autop is enabled I get (notice the closing `</p>` at the start?)

```
--- </p>
<h1>The title</h1>
xxx ... xxx ...
--- 
<section id="banner"><div class="wrap"></p>
<h1>The title</h1>
xxx ... xxx ...
</div></section>
```

When disabled I get

```
 --- 
<h1>The header</h1>
xxx ... xxx ...
 --- 
<section id="banner"><div class="wrap">
<h1>The header</h1>
xxx ... xxx ...    
</div></section>
```

**UPDATE**: I notice this happens only when I have a tag (e.g. `<h1>`) after my shortcode. Like:

```
[banner]
<h1>Test</h1>
```

If I have

```
[banner]
xxx ...
```

it's ok, except Wordpress adds a `<br />`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// replaces [banner ...] .. [/banner] with <!--banner ID--> before the_content filters run
add_filter('the_content', 'protect_my_shortcode', -100);
function protect_my_shortcode($content){
  return preg_replace_callback('/\[(banner)\b(.*?)(?:(\/))?\](.+?)\[\/\1\]/s', 'protect_my_shortcode_callback', $content);
}

function protect_my_shortcode_callback($matches){
  global $__banners;
  $id = '<!--banner '.count($__banners).'-->';

  $__banners[$id] = do_shortcode($matches[0]);
  // or '['.$matches[1].' '.$matches[2].']'.$matches[4].'[/'.$matches[1].']'
  // if you need to run any filters on the shortcode content ($matches[4])

  return $id;
}

// replaces <!--banner ID--> with the processed shortcode after all the filters run
add_filter('the_content', 'unprotect_my_shortcode', 100);
function unprotect_my_shortcode($content){
  global $__banners;
  return str_replace(array_keys($__banners), array_values($__banners), $content);
}
```

Comment: An improvement, but now a `<p>` is wrapping my banner `<p><section id="banner"></section></p>`. Whats wrong with http://i.imgur.com/kEthX.png (whats in my TinyMCE)

Comment: try to replace above `'<!--banner '.count($__banners).'-->';` with `'<div class="banner-'.count($__banners).'"></div>';` WP shouldn't wrap DIVs within <p>...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes this issue, but you can use the [`force_balance_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/force_balance_tags) function to clean up the markup after the fact.

Note that there are [some caveats](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89121/why-doesnt-default-wordpress-page-view-use-force-balance-tags) to using `force_balance_tags()` in practice.